Why are all rows of my matrix the same as the last row?
Can someone please help me find fault in my code? If I create a blank 2D matrix with static initial value, it returns the correct transposed matrix. Whereas if I create a blank matrix using a for loop, it is returning last row for all rows in the answer.
# Original Matrix :
[[1, 2, 3], 
[4, 5, 6], 
[7, 8, 9]]

# Expected Transpose :
[[1, 4, 7],
[2, 5, 8],
[3, 6, 9]]

# Actual Transpose :
[[3, 6, 9],
[3, 6, 9],
[3, 6, 9]]


# Transpose Matrix

def transpose_mtx(original):
    t_cols = len(original)
    t_rows = len(original[0])

    # creating a blank matrix with 0s of transpose shape
    row = [0 for _ in range(t_cols)]
    t_mtx = [row for _ in range(t_rows)]

    # t_mtx = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
    # if I keep this line instead, it returns correct answer
 
    # rows of original
    for i in range(len(original)):
        # columns of original
        for j in range(len(original[0])):
            # interchange items
            t_mtx[j][i] = original[i][j]
    
    return t_mtx


my_mtx = [[1,2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]]

print(transpose_mtx(my_mtx))


You are creating a List t_mtx which has 3 copies of the same sublist. So changes propagate. BTW - rather than Python Lists of Lists you should use Numpy array for a matrix and then it can be transposed directly.

Got it ! Thanks a lot. It worked. Changed the same list object "row" to separate copies of list for rows.

The problem is that you are using a list as an element of the list(as it should in the matrix), but the problem here is you are using all rows as the same list (that is row), and if you know that lists are mutable means they can update from anywhere and it will change for all reference of it.
Now in this case the t_mtx is using all rows as the same reference list(row), which means each time you update any row it will update all the rows, that is why your all rows are the same as the last row.
So here you can either create a new row each time or use the .copy() method to create a new copy of the row list.
t_mtx = [row.copy() for _ in range(t_rows)]

OUTPUT

Hope you understand, sorry for my bad English.

Got it ! Thanks a lot. It worked
I scratched my head checking manually across the whole inner loops to find where it was going wrong and wasted 2 hours. But finally, your answer helped.
So basically, the same list object "row" being used again for all rows is the issue, as the further changes are percolating everywhere since list is mutable. Thanks again !

You need to initialize a blank matric by creating separate lists for each row in the transpose matrix.
# Creating a blank matrix with 0s of transpose shape
t_mtx = [[0 for _ in range(t_cols)] for _ in range(t_rows)]


Thanks a lot ! It worked.
So basically, the same list object "row" being used again for all rows is the issue, as the further changes are percolating everywhere since list is mutable.
